# weak solution / variational calculus

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, calculus-of-variations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, weak-derivatives

We have a one dimensional boundary value problem $$ - (\omega u_x)_x = f \, \text{for} \, -1<x<1 \\ u(-1)=u(1) = 0 $$ with $$ \omega(x): = \sqrt{(1-x^2)} \, \text{and} \, f(x) := x \, \text{for} \, -1<x<1$$

Task: Find $l : H_{0}^{1} (-1,1,\omega) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ such that the variational equation $a(u,v) = l(v)$ for all $v \in  H_{0}^{1} (-1,1,\omega) $ holds and show with the Lax-Milgram Theorem that only one unique solution exists for the boundary problem in $H_{0}^{1} (-1,1,\omega)$.

The definition of $ H_{0}^{1} (-1,1,\omega) := \{ v \vert \, v(-1)=v(1)=0 ; \vert \vert v \vert \vert_{L^2(-1,1,\omega)}< \infty; \vert \vert v_x \vert \vert_{L^2(-1,1,\omega)}< \infty  \}$

My approach:

$$a(.,.) = H_{0}^{1} (-1,1,\omega) \times H_{0}^{1} (-1,1,\omega) \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $$
Thus $$ a(u,v) = \int_{\Omega} \nabla u \nabla v \, dx $$ and $$ l(v)=\int_{\Omega} fv \, dx =-\int_{\Omega} (\omega(x) u_x)_x v \,dx $$

I don't know if this approach makes sense. I am grateful for any help, as I am preparing for an exam and would like to understand how to solve such a task.

Comment: Why do you write $a(u,v)=\int_{\Omega}\nabla u\nabla v$ and then you say that $l(v)=-\int_{\Omega}(w(x)u_x)_xv$ ? Those are two different things.

Comment: I read the theory in our script and tried to apply it to the task. Like I said, I don#t know if it's right or usefull. Maybe I didn't really understand it either. Do you have a suggestion or an idea how to solve this? And could you please explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of $a$ needs to correspond to your differential operator, in this case $(wu_x)_x$. First off, multiply both sides by a test function $v$ and integrate:
$$ -\int_{[-1,1]}(wu_x)_xv = \int_{[-1,1]}fv$$

Since $a$ needs to be defined on $H_0^1(-1,1;w)$ you can only take one derivative; therefore you need to integrate by parts:
$$-\int_{[-1,1]}(wu_x)_xv=\int_{[-1,1]}wu_xv_x =:a(u,v). $$
Now all you have to do is prove that $a$ is coercive and bounded.

Comment: Thank you very much! What's about $l(v)$? Do I have to define $l(v) := \int_{[-1,1]} xv \, dx$? Because of the fact that $f(x) := x$

Comment: Right. Nevertheless Lax-Milgram proves that there exists a unique solution for any functional $l$ on $H_0^1(-1,1;w)$.

Comment: Thank you again! Can I argue the same way at this task: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3686461/variational-method-and-the-lax-milgram-theorem ? Even if the left side depends from the same function?

Comment: If both sides depend on $u$ then everything needs to be part of the bilinear form $a$.
The functional $l$ can't depend on $u$. Anyway, you already have an answer on that question.

Comment: So my functional $l$ is just a general $l(v) = \int_{[-1,1]} v \, dx$ or is $l(v) = 0$? In this case here I have a form for $l(v) = \int_{[-1,1]} xv \, dx$.